# Frankenstein's synonym

Tags: discussion, tags

Related to the recent question, [How to determine the firmware and firmware version of a Frankensbox fx-800?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/18141/4762) and given that:

1. The Frankensbox FX-800 is a *rebranded* Dedibot DF3;
2. The support for the Frankenbox appears to be, to say the least, somewhat lacking in the useful department;
3. There is *slightly* more useful support available for the Dedibot DF3 to be found on the web.

Would it be sensible to make the existing [frankensbox-fx-800](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frankensbox-fx-800) tag, actually an *synonym* of a new tag (say [dedibot-df3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dedibot-df3)), which, in addition to any brief summary of the DF3, also makes reference to the FX-800 being a rebranded DF3?

This linking of aliases *might* help people, who are looking for information on the Frankensbox, realise that they should widen their searches to include the DF3.

Does this aliasing fit in well with our recent reorganisation of tags for printer models and brands?

Comment: Not a regular here and having no knowledge about the product, so just a comment: if it's only a rebranding and there's no difference in the features/capabilities, I feel it makes sense to add a tag synonym.

Comment: Ah thanks, yes "synonym" not "alias". That's what I meant :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synonym is a solution to let people choose the tag they think is the correct one (the synonym), but gets converted to another tag (the target).

From [3D Printing Stack Exchange -> Help center -> Privileges](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms):

> ### What happens when a question is asked using a synonym?
>
> Any tags that match active synonyms will be automatically and silently changed from their original as-entered form to the tag that the synonym points to.

The downside is that there is no predefined synonym to choose from! (drop-down list)

E.g. if you make a synonym tag [frankensbox-fx-800](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frankensbox-fx-800) for the target tag [dedibot-df3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dedibot-df3), the user creating the tag to the question needs to be exactly typed in as `frankensbox-fx-800`, i.e. there is no pop-up for suggestions of the tag you are about to use. So, when the OP enters `fx800frankensbox` or `frankensbox-fx800` this might not work, and the user is not presented with the `frankensbox-fx-800` option...

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a bit annoying. So maybe just have two separate tags, and in the frankensbox tag, just state that it is really a DF-3? Mind you, it's not like we actually get many frankensbox questions... so we could just type the tag in ourselves (i.e. the active tagging members of the user base)

Comment: @Greenonline Actually, the OP has bought a Frankensbox, so it is a Frankensbox, not a Dedibot, so why would we want to make a synonym. It is better to mention in the tag description that the Frankensbox is now known under Dedibot.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant - leave it tagged as it is, but in the frankensbox tag description add the rebranding info. I'm not sure why I mentioned the other tag - I sort of thought that we should create a DF-3 tag anyway (purely to have a complete set), but I *now* realise that it is pointless as we don't actually have any questions about a DF-3 (yet). :-)

Comment: "E.g. if you make a synonym tag [tag:frankensbox-fx-800] for the target tag [tag:dedibot-df3], the user creating the tag to the question needs to be exactly typed in as `frankensbox-fx-800`, i.e. there is no pop-up for suggestions of the tag you are about to use." – This isn't entirely correct. If you start typing the name of the tag (even if you don't type out the whole thing) in the tag bar (i.e. when editing a post's tags), then if what you've typed is included in the tag name (or the tag description as well, which I think is a more recent change), the system will suggest that tag.

Comment: So in this case, if [tag:frankensbox-fx-800] is a synonym pointing to [tag:dedibot-df3], then if you start typing `frankensbox` in the tag area for a question, then the system will include [dedibot-df3] in the tags it suggests (if that's one of the top 6 results for the tag text you typed, at least). The same is true if you start typing `fx-800` instead, since it's also part of the name of the synonymized tag.